# Green achievements indicator overflows the button if above 1k

Tags: bug, design, top-bar

[image]

When hovering over the achievements indicator while the accumulated rep is above 1k, the number overflows the button below.

The button should resize itself when its contents are too large, or the rep should be rounded to something like "1.1k".

Comment: You're expected to click it sometimes, you know. ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard But...the rep...it builds up...so hypnotizingly! :D OK, I do click it, but I was out of town and on mobile for the past week so the rep kept accumulating.

Comment: I've heard of the Humblebrag, but I'm starting to believe there is also something called the Bugbrag.  At least on meta.